# strange behavior of jQuery resizable UI in FireFox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a div to which assigned resizable

when I start to resize it for the first time, its parent div suddenly become a little bigger and two scrollbar suddenly appear

This phenomenon happens in FireFox, in safari and chrome it works fine..

can anyone tell me how to fix it?

more detail:

I have a struct like this:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="noteboard">
        <div id="note"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

noteboard is a big board as large as the content which is also as large as the document.

then, note is a div draggable.

however, when I begin to drag note for the first time, the content div suddenly change it size.

at beginning, the content is 991*838

when I click down my mouse and move, the content's size changes to 976 * 838

```
#content{
    z-index:0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#noteboard{
    position: relative;
}

#note{
}
```

note's css is empty, but it has class ui-draggable and ui-resizable of jquery-ui and I set it draggable and resizable...

Comment: Just consider, without the problem code/markup/css *at least* (and a http://jsfiddle.net demo if possible and *highly preferable*), it's *very hard* to tell, short of guessing. Consider: http://sscce.org/

Comment: sorry..I'm not familiar with that....I have tried to use jsfiddle...but my problem involves jquery-ui for which I don't know how to put into jsfiddle...

Comment: Look on the left, below the dropdown that says `jQuery 1.7.1`: http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Uc/ Also, you can *Add Resources* (look a little further down on the left), ie, JS and CSS files.

Comment: strange....after I test some sample code in jsFiddle...suddenly FF works fine......

Comment: ok...I find the problem...involving box of CSS3...my content is display as box..so maybe some strange thing happens...I will look into it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set parent's overflow CSS parameter to hidden.

for example:

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow: hidden;"> 
  <div id="resizable"/> 
</div>
```